# Who is this green guy?

Tags: prison-architect

I just recently acquired a green/blue prisoner. I have never seen one before, so I don't know what to do.

[image]

Is he one of those 'convicted guards/staff members' or something? Do I need to put him in a special cell?

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's another one:

[image]

Comment: That is one of the developers of the game, he is just a normal prisoner and can be treated in the exact same was as all the others.

Comment: @Elliott Thanks! That should probably be an answer

Comment: The green guy is Luigi :)

Comment: You should not treat him like every other prisoner: Give him at least an hour of solitary confinement everytime you notice a bug.

Comment: The second one appears to be modeled after someone who bought the "your face in the game" package during the early crowdfunding phase (no longer available).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is one of the developers of the game. He is just a normal prisoner and can be treated in the exact same way as all the others.

As an additional note, occasionally the developers have been known to change some prisoner skins as a joke, so if you see someone like this just treat them as normal.

Comment: +1 Often the custom skins are seasonally themed e.g. Santa Clause around Christmas time

Comment: Mark Morris is [one of the founders of Introversion Software](http://www.introversion.co.uk/aboutus.html) and the producer of Prison Architect.